# Error al migrar en laravel 5.6.28

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

tengo problemas a la hora de hacer una migración con seed en laravel.

[image: error en consola]

Muchas gracias si me pueden ayudar.

Comment: ¿has realizado el comando **composer update**?... suele decirte que conflictos de versiones hay y actualiza o indica los requisitos minimos para funcionar correctamente.

Comment: En tu entorno local funciona bien? No creo que este sea el problema, pero quizás es de incompatibilidad definición/uso del siguiente método: declarado como `runningInConsole()` pero llamado como  `runingInConsole()`

Comment: muchas gracias, precisamente tenia el error al momento de llamar la función [runningInConsole()] @HCK